# Why is glycerol supplied/used as 87% solution?

Tags: microbiology, cell-culture

While preparing glycerol stocks of my transformed bacterial cells (DH5alpha) the protocol I had to follow was that I would make one 50% glycerol stock (500µl culture, 500µl glycerol 50%) and another 87% glycerol stock (850µl bacterial culture, 150µl glycerol 87%). 87 seems to be a very specific number. Any particular reason why 87% glycerol concentration is used?

Comment: In which protocol/reference did you find the 87% glycerol?

Comment: I think my lab protocol follows sambrook russel's molecular cloning.

Comment: Yes I will try to provide a proper reference.

Comment: Glycerol is typically sold at 87%, which just pushes back the question one step. Many years ago I was told that this is because of glycerol's hygroscopic nature, such that a higher concentration would tend to absorb water from the atmosphere and dilute itself anyway. Does this stop at 87%? Figure 1 from [Glycerine: an overview](http://www.aciscience.org/docs/glycerine_-_an_overview.pdf) suggests that 50% relative humidity might lead to a glycerol concentration that is in the ballpark of 87%, but 40 or 45% relative humidity looks closer.  Not definitive, so I'll leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, a glycerol stock will have a final concentration of 10-20% of glycerol. Glycerol is highly viscous. Pipetting higher concentrations of glycerol is difficult (especially for smaller volumes). Therefore a lower concentration such as a 50% solution (works for me) is convenient: add 300µl to 700µl of bacterial culture.

Regarding 87%: some vendors provide 87% glycerol along with anhydrous (>99%) glycerol. The reason is probably the same: it is easier to pipette 87%.

From a [vendor's website](https://www.applichem.com/en/shop/product-detail/as/glycerin-wasserfrei-ibiochemicai/):

> Glycerol is a component of several buffers, media or reagents in
>   biological research. It is supplied as glycerol anhydrous or 87 %, the
>   latter containing 13 % water. Both glycerols are from the same
>   quality, the 87 % glycerol has the advantage of a lower viscosity.
>   Anhydrous glycerol can be pipetted with difficulty only, especially at
>   low temperatures.

But the question is why 87% and not 90 or 80? See [Michal et al. (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5004369)  for a relationship between viscosity and concentration of glycerol-water mixtures.

[image]

Another graph plotted from the data given in the [document](http://www.aciscience.org/docs/glycerine_-_an_overview.pdf) mentioned by iayork in the [comments](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/85301/why-is-glycerol-supplied-used-as-87-solution/85309#comment151801_85301). Different coloured lines denote data at different temperatures (in °C). Original data from: [*The properties of ordinary water substance.* Compiled by N. E. Dorsey, New York (Reinhold), 1940](https://doi.org/10.1002/qj.49708134736).

[image]

So I am guessing that 87% must have been optimal beyond which the viscosity just shoots up rapidly with a small increase in concentration. I wish to reiterate that this is just my guess. I could not find a authoritative (in fact any) reasoning on why precisely 87% glycerol is (or was historically) supplied.

Comment: Thanks so much for such an well reasoned and knowledgeable reply. That ought to be the reason for using 87% glycerol stock.

Comment: I think this is more plausible than the hygroscopicity I was told was the reason, since 87% doesn't show an obvious connection with anything on the hygroscopic chart whereas it's a better match with viscosity. The vendor's comment you quote also strongly supports this. Upvoted!